Can someone tell me if the Giant Hornet colony was spared in the end?
In the anime Shinsekai Yori I don't think they made it clear if Kirimaru's Giant Hornet colony was spared or not. But maybe Manga-readers or novel-readers may have more information. Can you please let me know?

Related/possible dupe? How were the Giant Hornets actually defeated?

@AkiTanaka Nope. That is a different question.
